# Problems with installing InfluxDB on Ubuntu16.04

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to install InfluxDB on my linux server.
I ran `sudo apt-get install influxdb` and got the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  influxdb
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 158 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3160 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package influxdb.
(Reading database ... 146447 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../influxdb_0.10.0+dfsg1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking influxdb (0.10.0+dfsg1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.15) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up influxdb (0.10.0+dfsg1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.15) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
```

Then, to check the version of influx I ran `influxd` and got the version number 0.10.0.
The latest version is 1.7.3. So I uninstalled the current installation with: `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove influxdb` and tried: `sudo apt-get install influxdb=1.7.3` and got the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '1.7.2' for 'influxdb' was not found
```

I don't understand what seems to be the problem with this installation.
Why does it installs the previous version for me? When I tried the same thing on my Ubuntu 18.04 server I got the latest version of InfluxDB with no problems.
How can I get the latest version?

Comment: Check the repository used to get influxdb. Or you can download influxdb .deb package with fresh version manually and install it locally with dpkg.

Comment: @YuriLachin how can I check that?

Comment: Package repositories are defined in /etc/apt/ folder and its sub-folders. You can easily add InfluxData repository to your system following instructions in https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/introduction/installation/ After that apt-get should install fresh version of influxdb.